# sql query to count two columns with same values

Tags: sql

I've got a table with 2 columns with keywords, and I need to count the occurrence of them.
I can do that separately, one column at the time, and add the totals later, with a regular count,

```
select count (id), kw1 from mytable group by kw1
```

and the same for kw2, but I need to get the info straight from the db.

So the table is something like:

```
id       kw1          kw2
1         a            b
2         c            d 
3         b             
4         e            a
```

so the idea is to get how many times has been used each keyword, so the result should be something like:

```
'a'  2
'b'  2
'c'  1
'd'  1
'e'  1
```

Thanks in advance

PS: Sorry, I forgot, but just in case, I'm working on Oracle 10g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT kw, COUNT(kw)
FROM
(
   SELECT "kw1" AS kw FROM table1
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT "kw2"       FROM table1
) t
WHERE kw IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY kw
ORDER BY KW;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9d278/5)

This will give you:

```
KW   COUNT(KW)
a       2
b       2
c       1
d       1
e       1
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked, but I have some differences, I think it has to do with other fields, from other tables that I need to filter.... It's done.Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

It shoud looks something like this.

```
SELECT kw,SUM(kw)
FROM(
(SELECT kw1 AS kw, COUNT(kw1) 
FROM table
WHERE kw1 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY kw1) skw1

UNION ALL

(SELECT kw2, COUNT(kw2) 
FROM table
WHERE kw2 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY kw2) skw2
)
GROUP BY kw
ORDER BY kw
```

Previous answers don't perform a SUM operation after performing the UNION.

Comment: This query won't work because you get a syntax error for the table aliases skw1 / skw2 (not allowed there) and because you cannot SUM strings (either you have to use COUNT, or you should alias your COUNT columns from the inner query and SUM this column instead).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt you're totally right. As matter of fact, the sum should be performed on the second column of the subqueries. There's also a mistake about aliasing. I'm at work so I wasn't able to try it at the momento of posting the reply. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

use `union All` to combine two column data into one column & then count occurence

```
 SELECT cnt, COUNT(cnt)
    FROM
    (
       SELECT kw1 AS cnt FROM table
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT kw2       FROM table
    ) t
 WHERE cnt IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cnt
ORDER BY cnt;
```